# Android loading list of byte array images

Tags: java, android, arrays, image, android-glide

I have a possible issue (OOM) with loading list of images from DB. In my database, images are stored as BLOB. Those images are fetched and displayed in Fragment using RecyclerView.
Images are loaded using Glide and I'm using GridLayoutManager to display 3 images in one row(picture attached):

```
Glide
.with(context)
.load(image[])
.asBitmap()
.override(dimensionPixelSize)
.dontAnimate()
.centerCrop()
.placeholder(R.drawable.image)
.into(imageView);
```

[GridLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAVct.jpg)

When images are fetched from DB, I'm storing it in singleton class and then using this List of images when creating Adapter etc.

```
class ImageData {
    private List<ImageModel> images;

    private static final ImageDate instance = new ImageData();

    private ImageData() {
    }

    public static ImageData getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void setImages(List<ImageModel> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    public List<ImageModel> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

}
```

ImageModel class has byte[] for actual image and long timestamp fields.
Also, there is possibility to show full screen image onClick - in that case I'm creating DialogFragment with viewPager and ViewPagerAdapter is using the same list from singleton class.
The actual problem is that sometimes I can get OOM. This happens after 15/20min. of using the app and several times of closing and opening the app.
I know that Glide has memory and disk cache strategy, for example I tried with .skipMemoryCache(true) or diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE) but with no success.
Can you help me with some suggestion? If you need I can add some more code but basically I'm using ViewHolder pattern with RecyclerView and this Glide code for loading images is inside ViewHolder class.

Comment: `When images are fetched from DB, I'm storing it in singleton class` you should not do this, instead load image directly from DB whenever needed.

Comment: Ok, I will try in this way and remove Singleton class

Comment: `byte[] for actual image`. What exactly? Jpg? Png? What exactly do you store as BLOB?

Comment: Remove singleton class? Class is ok. Get rid of the images list as that takes up the memory.

Comment: I'm storing jpeg images as BLOB in my DB

Comment: @greenapps, how do you mean: " Get rid of the images list as that takes up the memory."? How else I can load my images from DB

Comment: Directly from DB as already has been suggested. Use no list as the list causes the OOM. Not that singlton class.

Comment: @greenapps can you explain little bit how to load directly.

Answer (score 0):

byte array are restricted by memory available to it on device. If you are creating byte array and not destroying it, you will run out of memory. I hope this helps.

Comment: The only time when I'm creating byte array is when I'm fetching images from DB: `ImageModel image = new Image(cursor.getBlog(...));`

Comment: Hi, I did not post an answer because I was 'between jobs' etc. etc. Anyway I figured out that the OOM issue was not with the list of images, but because I did not efficiently implement code for destroying fragments inside viewPager. I had viewPager with 5 fragments that were 'heavy' and with constantly changing screens, OOM appeared within 1 minute. I would like to post a code but I no longer have access to the repository.